# Do researchers do their own statistics?

Tags: research-process, statistics

I'm writing a small paper on statistics in science and I was wondering whether in most fields researchers do their own statistics, or do they usually have a statistician in the department to do it for them?

For example, say I am a researcher in psychology at a university and I designed and performed an experiment. I now have the data I wanted and it needs to be analysed. Will I do this myself or will I ask a statistician to do it for me? What is usual in science?

Comment: There are so many factors going into this that it's going to be impossible to answer.

Comment: "Do researchers do their own statistics?" - Yes. And no. And also sometimes. "Will I do this myself or will I ask a statistician to do it for me?" - This one is easier to answer: Yes.

Comment: This is not my field, but I am surprised at the combination of "designed an experiment" and "do not know how to analyze the data". I naively expect that the integral part of the experiment's design is to decide on how the data will be analyzed before it is collected.

Comment: A researcher in such a field that _can't_ do their own statistics isn't going to get very far. Of course, consultations with experts is generally useful and specialization is also useful. But you'd better understand it or you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: We may be able to answer this question, if you tell us the field. I can tell you that most psychologists and social scientists do their own statistics.

Comment: @Buffy I suppose it should be this way, but in fact it is isn't. Anecdotally, many researchers in the social sciences plug their numbers into SPSS and it gives them an R and hopefully "some stars". I wouldn't be surprised if practices in other disciplines were similar.

Answer (score 4):

Both scenarios are quite common, and commonality varies by discipline - but I can tell you for certain both happen enough that you should not be surprised by either case. There is also somewhat of a hybrid approach, where many researchers do their own statistics (or have a favorite collaborator who does it for them as part of their contribution) but they may consult with a statistician for some additional guidance or advice, formally or informally. If I were forced to guess, I'd say that in most social science fields I'm familiar with (many with connections to Psychology) I'd be somewhat surprised if less than 75% of statistical analysis was handled by non-statisticians.

In practice, it tends to vary by individual study as well, and will change over time with any given researcher or team. Some people do certain kinds of stats only (ANOVA for everything, yay!), and if they can't do that they won't do any - or they just do an ANOVA anyway. Some people do no stats of any kind, ever. Some people develop a quantitative focus and start doing their own stats, and then become known as "the stats person" and end up becoming involved as a collaborator for others with a focus on research design and analysis, even as they continue with non-stats tasks (coming up with their own research ideas, running their own studies, etc.). Some people end up running into problems they realize don't fit the stats they are comfortable with, and work together with an outside person (consultant, statistician, etc.) to guide them or handle the analysis, but only for that problem (ex: they realized they needed a survival analysis but hadn't done that before, so they wanted to be sure they were going about it reasonably but then did the actual analysis mostly themselves).

So, in a nutshell: researchers of all kinds do stats always, sometimes, and never, and the mix varies heavily by discipline, problem type, and weather.